# Proving $|\operatorname{Aut}(E/F)|\leq\left[E:F\right]$ for $E$ splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, automorphism-group

> Let $F$ be a field and $E$ be a spliting field of some $f(x)\in F\left[x\right]$, how does one prove that
>
> $$|\operatorname{Aut}(E/F)|\leq\left[E:F\right]?$$

I have no idea since I know $\operatorname{Aut}(E)$ can be humongous.

When does the equality hold?

Answer (score 0):

In this context I believe $Aut(E/F)$ refers to the Galois group of $E/F$, which is the set of all $F$-automorphisms of $E$, as opposed to the group of ALL automorphisms of E. Since E is a splitting field it is finitely generated and it turns out such an automorphism is completely determined by its action on the generators. Equality holds when the extension is also separable. This is part of the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory. The proof is readily found in most Algebra texts. I can recommend Algebra by Mark Sepanski for its development of this particular topic.

Comment: Aut(E/F) is a set of all automorphisms whoch sets F. What does "completely determined by its action on the generators" mean? I can imagine that some automorphism in Aut(E/F) send a generator to bzillion possibilities in E, or how does one prove there are finitely many of these automorphisms?

Comment: @Machinato Yes, that's correct. Its called the Galois group of E over F. What I mean is that $E = F(a_1,a_2,...a_n)$ (by the assumption that it is a splitting field) and it turns out if $\sigma , \tau \in Aut(E/F)$ and $\sigma (a_i) = \tau (a_i)$ for all $i$ then $\sigma = \tau$. So immediately from combinatorics alone the order of $Aut(E/F)$ is bounded by $n!$.

Comment: @Machinato I should add to my above comment that each automorphism must map a generator to another generator. i.e. $\sigma(a_i) = a_j$ for some $j$. The proof of your question itself isn't difficult, it's just involved....many lemmas.

Comment: @David_Reed Sure number of automorphisms is bounded, but I wanted proof of the equality. For example for polynomial (x²-2)(x²-3) its splitting field E adds ±√2, ±√3 to rationals (our F). In total 4 roots. However, there are not 4! automorphisms which fix F since there is no σ isomorphism which would transform √2 to √3. And of course [E:F] (degree of extension) is also not 4!. There are multiple definitions of Galois group. Let's say Galois group is a group Aut(E/F) where E is a splitting field of some separable (distinct roots) polynomial. How then one can generally show that |Aut(E/F)|=[E:F]?

Comment: @machinato Yes it was just a simple combinatorial argument, since you characterized the possible order of the group as potentially "humungous". Also, the proof I'm familiar with of the inequality requires the knowledge that a finite extension corresponds to a finite galois group, so its sort of a lemma in that sense. I wish it was something that can be answered so simply, but in truth as I said it would take a significant amount of time to type up (at least using the development I learned). I expect that's why nobody wanted to answer. The best I can do Is point you to a book that has it.